# Set up hotkey for collapse a panel

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Our project use JSF 2.2 primeface 5.1.

I have a toggleable panel, the collapse attribute set to true.

```
<p:panel id="panel1" toggleable="true" collapsed="true">
...
</p:panel>
```

How can I set a p:hotkey in the jsf page to change the attribute collapsed to false ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At a basic level, you can expand the pane with:

```
<p:hotkey bind="ctrl+s" handler="thePanelWidgetVar.expand();" />
```

If what you really want is to toggle the state of the panel, you could just call the `collapse()` and `expand()` on the panel directly. Obviously, you need to check the current state of the panel to determine what to call. You can collapse it all into the following script:

```
 <script>
      function togglePanelState (thePanel){

        if(thePanel.cfg.collapsed){
             thePanel.expand();
         }else{
             thePanel.collapse();
         }
      }
 </script>
```

You could then use `togglePanelState` thus

```
 <p:hotkey bind="ctrl+s" handler="togglePanelState(thePanelWidgetVar);" />
```

**EDIT:**

Thanks to Hatem Alimam for pointing out that a convenience method similar to my implementation of `togglePanelState` exists out of the box in PF 5.1, in the form of a `toggle()` function. Using that, you could then have instead:

```
 <p:hotkey bind="ctrl+s" handler="PF('thePanelWidgetVar').toggle();" />
```

Comment: The question target is PF 5.1, you might need to update your answer with the shortcut for accessing the widgets, `PF('thePanelWidgetVar')`. Also there's no need to have a function to do the toggling (which will not call the onShow handlers!), the simplest format would be `handler="PF('thePanelWidgetVar').toggle()"` and would be friendly with the events :)

Comment: Thanks for the update @HatemAlimam, I'll include it.